# change proxy username -ubuntuone on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one, password, proxy

ubuntuone asked for my proxy username during install, i used it for a while then the password had to be changed. now one is still using the old password.
Tried to reinstall but the password dialog cannot be started.

is there a way of changing the password, or atleast accessing my docs without the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One does not have its own proxy settings. It uses the system settings for proxy on Windows. You can change these settings inside Internet Explorer preferences, or in the Control Panel for Internet, I believe.